# OpenGL and OSX Mavericks - error including OpenGL headers

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, compiler-errors

OSX 10.9, XCode 5.1, targeting ios7 and trying to use some OpenGL.

I am including:

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <OpenGL/glext.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

Which XCode doesn't find.

I have added the `OpenGLES.framework` to my target as well.

When I try and auto-complete the `#includes` it shows me `OpenGL/gl.h`, but then the compiler says it cannot find it.

The exact error:

```
fatal error: 'OpenGL/gl.h' file not found
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
          ^
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact errors you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new OpenGL project for iOS in XCode to view the configurations they use for OpenGL.

From what i see, the OpenGL framework is not for iOS. You must use OpenGLES for mobile devices. If you want to include the `gl.h` header. You need to `#include OpenGLES/ES3/gl.h`.

EDIT: Here's some links for the OpenGLES framework:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES#OpenGL_ES_3.0
- http://www.khronos.org/opengles/
- https://developer.apple.com/opengl-es/

Hope this helps!

Ian

Comment: @Ian, I just created a new OpenGL project too. Thank you for pointing this out. I was paying attention to the SuperBible 4.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically linking the mac to Mac OpenGL libraries should fix the problem, but didn't on my side:
 sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers /usr/local/include/GL